# Converting ITE to ROBDD form

Tags: boolean-algebra, trees, diagram-chasing, decision-trees

I need to convert expression $(A \vee C) \wedge (B \vee D) \wedge (A \vee B)$ from ITE tree form to ROBDD form.

**ITE FORM**

[image]

To convert to ROBDD I used the following steps:

- joining end nodes
- joining isomorphic subgraphs
- elimination of redundant nodes

**ROBDD FORM**

[image]

Is my ROBDD form correct? Could you please help me?